# 未経験者がPHPとJavaScriptを勉強する際、本だと出版年数は何年以降を選べばいいですか？

Tags: javascript, php

未経験者ですが、プログラミング言語PHPとJavaScriptを本で独学で勉強したいです。

プログラミング言語は何年かすると仕様が変わったりすると聞きました。

本なら出版年数何年以降を選べば良いでしょうか？

またどちらの言語も難しくて分かりやすい本に出会えてません。おすすめの本がありましたら、教えください。

どうぞ宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

> プログラミング言語は何年かすると仕様が変わったりすると聞きました。
> 本なら出版年数何年以降を選べば良いでしょうか？

今年 or 昨年 出版されたものを選ばれてはどうでしょうか？

> またどちらの言語も難しくて分かりやすい本に出会えてません。

書籍の前書きを読んで、その書籍の説明範囲や対象読者がご自身に合っているかを確認されると良いと思います。内容以外にも文体等の好みもありますので、実際に書店や図書館で本を手に取り中身を確認してから購入すると失敗が少ないかと思います。
また誤植等が多いと学習が進みませんので、購入前に正誤表が出ていないか確認するのも良いでしょう。

また書籍以外にも動画学習の方が分かりやすいという人もいますので、動画学習を取り入れるという手もあります。（個人的には併用が良いと思っています。）

Comment: ありがとうございます。動画もいいのですね。見てみようと思います！ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

この業界、ドッグイヤーとか（死語）マウスイヤーとか（死語）言われるわけで、言語仕様書なり解説書なりを「常に最新」で追いかけたいのなら書籍でなくて web に頼らざるを得ないのが現状です。また、実際の処理系は安定性重視で最新言語仕様バージョンに追従していないなんてこともごく普通にあります。だから最新を追究するのはお勧めできません。本を読むだけで手を動かさずに身につくことはあり得ないので、何らかの形で実処理系を用意するのがおすすめです。レンタルサーバ業者と契約して使えることを確認した処理系バージョンとか、あなたが自分の仮想マシンに導入するとかした処理系バージョンに対応する書籍を探してみるのが良いと思われます。
（逆でも可。書籍に合わせた処理系バージョンを導入する）

オイラにとって良かった書籍があなたにとっても良いかというとそんなことはないので、書籍のおすすめはできないです。 SO の方針的にも買い物リスト質問は非推奨となっています。

# PHP はバック javascript はフロントで、全く役割が違うから同時に勉強すると混乱するの必至かと。最初はどちらか片方だけ集中してやるほうがいいと思われるっス。

Comment: ありがとうございます。実際にサイトやプログラムなどを作って、それに合ったものを勉強していく方がが良いということですね？ウェブで勉強するのが最新のものを勉強できそうだけど、最新を追いかけるのはあまり良くないという事ですね？何かサイトを作りたいけれど、基礎から勉強していました。なかなか進まなかったので、アドバイス頂き助かりました。ありがとうございます。

Comment: 処理系のバージョンと言語仕様のバージョンは区別してくださいね！この２つは全く違うものっス。 // web 系はすそ野が広い（広すぎる）ので、ちょっとしたことを実装したくても知らなきゃならないことが山のようにあるため、実は入門向きではないのです。でも興味がないことは続けられないので、いろいろやってみましょう。ファイ！

Comment: ありがとうございます。処理系、言語仕様とは何か調べてみましたが、いまいち分かりません汗　ここで説明するのも難しいですかね？もう少し勉強してみます。ありがとうございます。

Comment: （いまいち）わからないのなら別質問を挙げてみよう！そうすると誰かが回答してくれると思うっス。

Comment: そうですね。ありがとうございました。大変助かりました。

Comment: 若干割り込みになってしまうかもしれませんが補足として以下買い物リスト質問についてのリンクです。[買い物リスト質問について](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1381/x%e3%81%ae%e4%b8%80%e8%a6%a7%e3%81%8c%e7%9f%a5%e3%82%8a%e3%81%9f%e3%81%84-%e3%81%a8%e3%81%84%e3%81%86%e8%b3%aa%e5%95%8f%e3%81%ae%e5%82%be%e5%90%91%e3%81%a8%e9%96%a2%e9%80%a3%e3%82%b5%e3%82%a4%e3%83%88%e3%81%a7%e3%81%ae%e5%af%be%e5%bf%9c/1382#1382)